# How to force docker-compose to download a new image when using docker hub?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerhub

I have a docker-compose.yml file which takes the image svka4019/notes2:latest from the docker hub.
However, if I change the image build it and push it, when I run docker-compose it just uses the one it has already downloaded before.
Here is the docker-compose.yml:

```
springboot-docker-compose-app-container: 
    image: svka4019/notes2:latest
    ports:
      - "80:5001"
    depends_on:
    - friendservice
    networks:
    - mynet
    container_name: base_notes
  friendservice:
    build: ./Pirmas
    command: python app.py
    ports:
    - 5000:5000
    container_name: friend
    networks:
    - mynet
    
networks:
    mynet:
```

And the command I use for building and running: `docker-compose up --build -d`.
For updating the image in docker-hub I use:

```
docker build -t svka4019/notes2
docker push svka4019/notes2
```

If I use methods as no-cache it just rebuilds friendService container and skips the base one.

Comment: You can try deleting the image with docker image rm image_name

Comment: `latest` is very confusing. It is purely a string though and does not have any specific functionality. Think of it as just `foo`. Even though you're rebuilding your image, when docker-compose runs, it looks for `x:latest`, finds it locally (does not check whether it differs from what's posted to the registry) and proceeds. A better approach may be to change your tags as you revise versions or perhaps better to use the image manifest (`sha256:....`) as this explicitly references a unique version of the image and will (very probably) change every time you change the image.

Comment: @DazWilkin Could you give an example on how to use the manifest instead of image:tag?

Comment: `docker push ...[[username]]/[[repo]]:[[tag]]`, if successful, outputs `[[tag]]: digest: sha256:[digest]] size: [[size]`. Other registries (dockerhub's UI appears to not provide this) allow you to list the digests for repositories|images. Using dockerhub, to retrieve the digest value, you need to e.g. `docker pull [[username]]/[[repo]]:[[tag]]` and, on success, it will report `Digest: sha256:[[digest]]`. `[[digest]]` (32 hex characters == 256 bits) is the value you need. You reference it `[[username]]/[[repo]]@sha256:[[digest]]` **NB** `@` not `:` after `[[repo]]`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As @DazWilkin pointed out in the comments, using latest tag should be used carefully. Not only can it introduce bugs in your app if latest comes with BC breaks, but it also doesn't indicate that a new update must be performed on your machine if you already have an image 'latest'.

In your case, what you have to do should you want to keep using latest, is to simply call:

```
docker-compose pull
```

In case you are building your own image, then you must do:

```
docker-compose build --pull
```

The latter will tell docker-compose to first pull the base image before building your custom image.

Comment: If I want to use the docker-compose up command, is my only option to do "docker-compose pull && docker-compose up --build -d" ?

Comment: afaik yes. What we did for example for one of our projects, is to keep track of the last time a pull was done and the systems does it for the user. But then you need some scripting in between like via a Makefile or a custom shell script.